In sonartype Nexus log: Problem generating browse nodes for Asset
WARN  [event-15-thread-13378]  anonymous org.sonatype.nexus.repository.browse.internal.orient.OrientBrowseNodeManager - Problem generating browse nodes for Asset{metadata=AttachedEntityMetadata{schema=asset, document=#20:16549{bucket:#16:4,format:npm,last_updated:Tue Jul 09 10:26:28 CEST 2024,attributes:[5],component:#17:16937,name:lru-cache/-/lru-cache-6.0.0.tgz,size:5788,content_type:application/x-tgz,created_by:jenkinsDeploy,created_by_ip:127.0.0.1,blob_ref:default@1F73C764-C7337074-DD41979E-00B8D996-3B3EF577:db163c09-9d50-4e68-9896-2f28137e29c5,last_downloaded:Thu Jun 20 08:53:35 CEST 2024,blob_created:Fri Oct 20 12:47:40 CEST 2023,blob_updated:Fri Oct 20 12:47:40 CEST 2023} v97}, name=lru-cache/-/lru-cache-6.0.0.tgz}
org.sonatype.nexus.repository.browse.internal.orient.BrowseNodeCollisionException: Node already has an asset
    DB name="component"
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.browse.internal.orient.BrowseNodeEntityAdapter.createAssetNode(BrowseNodeEntityAdapter.java:306)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.repository.browse.internal.orient.OrientBrowseNodeStore.lambda$1(OrientBrowseNodeStore.java:168)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.orient.transaction.OrientOperations.lambda$2(OrientOperations.java:62)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.OperationPoint.lambda$0(OperationPoint.java:53)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.OperationPoint.proceed(OperationPoint.java:64)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.transaction.TransactionalWrapper.proceedWithTransaction(TransactionalWrapper.java:58)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.tra

In the npm repository then I find 2 different identic component: for example, in this case, lru-cache-6.0.0.tgz

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would understand because I have this WARN, what I can do to solve it? Because the same identical component, with the same versione is twice in the same repository? How can delete all the duplicate in a massive way?
